# If statement that checks html input element value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to be able to test the value of employee ID against the value of the input element.

```
<input type="hidden" id="pEmployeeID" />

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   if (item.EmployeeID = #pEmployeeID.value)
     {

     }
}
```

I am doing this because I have a div that appears on top of the view as a modal pop up. I wanted to be able to transfer a certain value from the View to the div. i have done this by using jQuery to set the value of the hidden input tag as the value that I want to transfer from the view to this div within the view.

Comment: why "=" ? its assignment operator. You should use "==" operator @Shanah Jr Suping

Comment: How are you assigning value to hidden field? using `JavaScript` or `razor`?

Comment: Note that the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor is server-side so it won't be able to see the value of the input as this will be changed on the client-side from what I can tell.

You could perhaps instead call a partial view via ajax when the hidden input's value changes and use that to determine what to show in the partial view. Then replace the appropriate section on your page with what is return from your partial.